# Is it possible to have a regression with some variables differentiated and some not?

Tags: multiple-regression, stationarity, differences

I have some indipendent variables stationary at level, some stationary in first difference and one stationary in log first difference. Is it possible to run a regression with variables with different transformation? My dependent variable is stationary both in first difference and log first difference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can run every regression you want to with transformed variables. The twist comes with the interpretation. So generally speaking your model selection should be guided by a theoretical model in your mind.

It is also important to note that ordinary first differences $\Delta y_t =y_t-y_{t-1}$ have another interpretation as log-differences $\Delta \log(y_t) =\log(y_t)-\log(y_{t-1})=\log(y_t/y_{t-1})\approx(y_t - y_{t-1})/y_{t-1}$ for small changes.

If you start with a theoretical based model like

$$ y_t =\beta_0+\rho y_{t-1}+\beta_1t+\beta_2x_t+\beta_3z_t+\eta_t $$ and it is not stationary in levels you might apply first differences, leading to

$$ \Delta y_t =\beta_1+\rho \Delta y_{t-1}+\beta_2\Delta x_t+\beta_3\Delta z_t+\Delta\eta_t .$$  The parameter estimates can be interpreted as in the levels model (as long the assumptions on on $\eta_t$ convey to $\Delta\eta_t$). Which is often easier than an interpretation in terms of first differences.

But if you have a covariate that is stationary in the level ($x_t$) and one after log differences ($z_t$), you start with something like

$$ y_t =\beta_0+\rho y_{t-1}+\beta_1t+\beta_2x_t+\beta_3\log(z_t)+\eta_t $$ 
and your transformed model is given by (if the dependend variable ist FD stationary)
$$ \Delta y_t =\beta_1+\rho \Delta y_{t-1}+\beta_2\Delta x_t+\beta_3\Delta \log(z_t)+\Delta\eta_t  $$

where the interpretation of the parameters remains as above. I.e. you still can  interpreted the $\beta_3$ as a level-log effect, which is far easier then interpreting the effect of the log-differences on the first differences.

To make a long story short, I argue that when it comes to transformation of variables it is very important to think about the initial equation from which one starts. It is also important to think about the relations and interpretations of coefficients once different transformations are applied to the variable.

Comment: i understand your point, your answer it's very helpful! Let's call the independent variable that is stationary at log first difference M. I have no apparent justification to consider its logarithm instead that the variable at level. From a mere computational and soundness point of view, it's correct to mix in a model variables in first difference, variables in log first difference and variable at level?